# Oozie null pointer exception when submitting jobs

Tags: cloudera, oozie, oozie-coordinator

Just trying to run a very simple word count example but getting the following null pointer when submitting the job:

oozie job -oozie=http://localhost:11000/oozie/ -config job.properties -run

```
[cloudera@localhost Oozie_Example]$ oozie job -oozie=http://localhost:11000/oozie/ -config job.properties -run
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2714)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:477)
    at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient$JobSubmit.call(OozieClient.java:586)
    at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient$JobSubmit.call(OozieClient.java:561)
    at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient$ClientCallable.call(OozieClient.java:479)
    at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.run(OozieClient.java:655)
    at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.jobCommand(OozieCLI.java:918)
    at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.processCommand(OozieCLI.java:579)
    at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.run(OozieCLI.java:552)
    at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.main(OozieCLI.java:199)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(ByteArrayInputStream.java:106)
    at sun.misc.CharacterEncoder.encode(CharacterEncoder.java:188)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.NegotiateAuthentication.setHeaders(NegotiateAuthentication.java:156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1482)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    ... 8 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

here is my job properties file:

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8021
queueName=default


inputDir=${nameNode}/user/dev/oozie/workflow/wordcount/input/ 
outputDir=${nameNode}/user/dev/oozie/workflow/wordcount/output/

oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/user/oozie/workflow/wordcount/lib
oozie.use.system.libpath=true

user.name=dev

oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/oozie/workflow/wordcount/
```

Any ideas? It happens pretty early so I think it has something to do with Oozie or namenode.

Comment: It's not happening in Oozie itself, it's a client side error. That said, I suspect it's trying to authenticate and failing...

Comment: maybe kerberos related? I am using a kerberzied vm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would like to add to the answer of this question.

When oozie client got a NullPointerException, that usually means that request caused server thread failure. If you want to find out the "true" reason, you should look at the server log such as /var/log/oozie/oozie.log for CDH.

There you will find detailed stacktrace. That proved to be very helpful. At least in our case, it tells exactly what happened such as "a hdfs workflow file doesn't exist, blah..."

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.NullPointerException` is due to an error in your job.properties file.

Have you placed the workflow XML into HDFS?  Also, you should specify:

```
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/oozie/workflow/wordcount/my-workflow.xml
```

Comment: yes I hae the workflow xml in hdfs, and have tried specifing the xml directly

Comment: You're probably missing an assignment statement or something is not where you said it would be in the job.properties file.

Comment: yeah related to my job properties file was not pointing to a correct namenode